# Google Play Beta, after more than a day, I still don't see the beta version of my app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I uploaded a beta version of my app. I created a Google+ community with me in it. I added that Google+ Community to the Beta. I went to the invite link on my Android device and opted into the Beta. I've waited more than a day but still don't see the beta version on my device or in the Google Play store. I've tried clearing data in the Google Play app (via the Settings) and rebooting.

I still only see the production version of the app. What am I missing?

Comment: **"I've tried clearing data in the Google Play app"** : What do you mean exactly? Do you mean you've uninstalled the app from your device?

Comment: I opened the Settings app, then to Manage Applications, to Google Play, then tapped Clear Cache and tapped Clear Data.

Comment: Is the version on your device a debug build or a release build? Is the version you have uploaded to the Beta testing area a debug or release build? If you have one type on the device and have uploaded another to the Beta area you'll have problems as it's not possible to upgrade from debug to release (and vice versa) due to different keys used to sign the apk. If that's the case uninstalling completely should fix things. I upload release builds so my Beta testers don't have to uninstall but I often forget my device has a debug build installed so have to uninstall to see the Beta update.

Comment: I only have one set of keys that I use to sign when I upload, and I've also deleted the app from the device multiple times.